# "Automatically turn URLs and email addresses into links" not working on Wygwam fields

Tags: ee2, pixelandtonic, wygwam, channel

I've got a channel using several kinds of fields (textarea, matrix, wygwam), and I need the "Automatically turn URLs and email addresses into links" functionality on the channel. I've set the option in the channel preferences, and it works as expected for the textarea field. The wygwam field, however, does't convert the same text into a link.

I'm on EE 2.7.2 and Wygwam 3.2.1

I've never had this problem before with other versions (of EE and Wygwam) - anyone else ever experience something similar?

Comment: Did this just happen recently on an upgrade? Or is this a new site? I ask because sometimes I've had to go back to a field and just "resave" it and magically fixes things.

Comment: It's on a a new site. I've tried resaving the entries, but it doesn't change at all.

Comment: I don't mean resaving entries, i mean resaving the field.

Comment: I just tried resaving the field - no change.

Comment: Bit of a head scratcher. At this point might as well contact P&T, I think. They had issues w/ this before but that was SEVERAL versions ago.

Answer (score 1):

You might look to see how your copy is being formatted on output. Sometimes I have had issues with this if I Restrict allowed HTML in the Wygwam field and have that automatic linking enabled.

Do you have any advanced settings enabled or custom CSS? This can effect it too.